# Is it possible to see date of update of row mysql?

Tags: mysql, row, business-intelligence

I'd like to see the update date per-row in a table (InnoDB) in mysql.

Is it possible? The only thing I found is the statistics on a table, not row.

```
SHOW TABLE STATUS
```

Any suggestions appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible, if you want to track the updates or inserts of 'row' in a table, you have to manually create a logic to do so, for example you can use triggers , to maintain the track of all changes and updates of the 'rows' in any other table.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can see specific informations like this for a row.

What I usually do is that I create a column `creation_date` and `modification_date` in all my tables and then I fill them for each `INSERT` or `UPDATE` query with [the function NOW()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)

You can also create your table this way :

```
CREATE TABLE [name]
[other colmns]
creation_date DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

For this, see [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870536/mysql-automatically-store-record-creation-timestamp).