# What is the syntax error in this simple SQL query?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

The best information I can get is

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'desc VARCHAR (1000), postdate DATETIME DEFAULT
>   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)' at line 1

about my query

```
$wpdb->query("CREATE TABLE jobs (id MEDIUMINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY, title VARCHAR (50), desc VARCHAR (1000), postdate DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) $charset_collate")
```

What is the error? I know it's probably obvious, so forgive me (I'm a n00b). Regarding the `postdate` column, I was taking the syntax straight from the answer on [mysql automatically store record creation timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870536/mysql-automatically-store-record-creation-timestamp).

Comment: desc is a reserved word. The error in the error message is nearly always at, or immediately to the left of, the first word in the error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`desc` is a [reserved keyword in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and needs to be escaped by backticks.

```
... , `desc` VARCHAR (1000) ...
```

Comment: or... better idea... not used as a table/column identifier

Comment: I could've easily put in an answer for this, and is the 2nd one in 24 hours. why don't you just mark these as duplicates?