# Automatically set a Javascript timestamp (with milliseconds) when creating a record

Tags: mysql

I am using MySql and I have a field of type `BIGINT(20).

I realise that I can use CURRENT_TIMESTAMP as default [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4870536/mysql-automatically-store-record-creation-timestamp).

However, how do I assign, by default, a javascript-like timestamp, which includes milliseconds?

I am happy to just have the "000" at the end if there is no other way to have a millisecond-precise timestamp.

**UPDATE:** Please note that the question is based on leaving the column type as BIGINT(20)

Comment: I use node but this is totally unrelated to the language used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic answer to your question is you can't, as `BIGINT` columns can not have `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a default value.

If you change your column type to `TIMESTAMP(3)` it will record timestamps with 3 decimal places of precision (i.e. down to milliseconds). You can have up to 6 decimal places. See the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/fractional-seconds.html). In this situation you will also want to change your default to `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)`.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=568b61cfefb3121f778f3b589d157887)

A workaround to make it *appear* as if the column is a `BIGINT` would be to create a `VIEW` on the table using `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` for reading e.g.

```
CREATE VIEW jobs_us AS
SELECT ..., UNIX_TIMESTAMP(added) AS added 
FROM jobs
```

and use `INSERT` and `UPDATE` triggers to convert integer values to `TIMESTAMP` format using `FROM_UNIXTIME` e.g.

```
CREATE TRIGGER jobs_added BEFORE INSERT ON jobs
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF NEW.added IS NOT NULL THEN
        SET NEW.added = FROM_UNIXTIME(NEW.added);
    END IF;
END
```

Comment: So just `ALTER TABLE jobs ALTER COLUMN added SET DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)` and that's it?

Comment: It should be `ALTER TABLE jobs MODIFY added TIMESTAMP(3) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3)`

Comment: But I wanted the column to stay as a BIGINT(20) rather than timestamp(3)... If I run `ALTER TABLE jobs MODIFY added TIMESTAMP(3) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3);` I get `ERROR 1292 (22007): Incorrect datetime value: '1553893854362' for column 'added' at row 1`. If I run `ALTER TABLE jobs MODIFY added BIGINT(20) DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP(3);` I get `ERROR 1067 (42000): Invalid default value for 'added'`

Comment: @Merc you can't specify `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` as a default value for a `BIGINT` column, it can only be a default for a Date or Time type column. See my updated demo for how you can translate to/from unix timestamps using the `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` and `FROM_UNIXTIME` functions

Comment: But you can't assign a function as default right...?

Comment: @Merc that is correct, MySQL doesn't allow functions in default values.

Comment: So the answer to my original question, really, is "you can't"?

Comment: @Merc indeed. About the only thing you can do is use a timestamp data type and create a view which fetched that as a unix timestamp e.g. `CREATE VIEW jobs_us AS SELECT ..., UNIX_TIMESTAMP(added) AS added FROM jobs` and then use a trigger to convert timestamp values on insert/update using `FROM_UNIXTIME`.

Comment: Can you add this to the answer? I will accept it straight after that